# Arch Linux Issues with xorgxrdp and xfce4 windows manager

Tags: arch-linux, xrdp, rdp

I'm trying to use xrdp to RDP from my windows machine to my linux box(specifically xorg xrdp as mentioned in the Arch Linux wiki for setting up RDP). I'm having an issue with what I believe to be my desktop environment (xfce4) causing my RDP connection to be terminated. I have provided the snippets from XRDP and XRDP-Sesman below. I ssh'd in and decided to see what was happening on the linux box whenever I tried to connect with my Windows RDP client.

I do get a login box, and the login seems to succeed. I have tried a lot of different solutions involving making sure:

- `.xsessions` features the line `xfce4-session`
- `Xwrapper` is setup to allow any user to connect
- that my `.xinitrc` executes `startxfce4`
- set a keep alive timer within the `.ini` file

**xrdp.log**

```
[20190730-18:33:02] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: connect failed trying again...
[20190730-18:33:02] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: error in trans_connect chan
[20190730-18:33:02] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:51792)
[20190730-18:33:02] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.64.5.120:3389)
[20190730-18:33:02] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20190730-18:33:02] [DEBUG] Closed socket 19 (AF_UNIX)
[20190730-18:33:02] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20190730-18:33:23] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET connection received from 10.64.27.2 port 33394
[20190730-18:33:23] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.64.5.120:3389)
[20190730-18:33:23] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:3389)
[20190730-18:33:23] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20190730-18:33:23] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20190730-18:33:23] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20190730-18:33:23] [DEBUG] TLSv1.1 enabled
[20190730-18:33:23] [DEBUG] TLSv1 enabled
[20190730-18:33:23] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20190730-18:33:23] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.64.5.120:3389)
[20190730-18:33:25] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET connection received from 10.64.27.2 port 45509
[20190730-18:33:25] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.64.5.120:3389)
[20190730-18:33:25] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:3389)
[20190730-18:33:25] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20190730-18:33:25] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20190730-18:33:25] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20190730-18:33:25] [DEBUG] TLSv1.1 enabled
[20190730-18:33:25] [DEBUG] TLSv1 enabled
[20190730-18:33:25] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20190730-18:33:25] [INFO ] connected client computer name: DESKTOP-0C7KOCP
[20190730-18:33:25] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpdr chan_id 1004 flags 0x80800000
[20190730-18:33:25] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpsnd chan_id 1005 flags 0xc0000000
[20190730-18:33:25] [INFO ] adding channel item name cliprdr chan_id 1006 flags 0xc0a00000
[20190730-18:33:25] [INFO ] adding channel item name drdynvc chan_id 1007 flags 0xc0800000
[20190730-18:33:25] [INFO ] TLS connection established from 10.64.27.2 port 45509: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
[20190730-18:33:25] [DEBUG] xrdp_00002b80_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20190730-18:33:25] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000809.ini
[20190730-18:33:25] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000809 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20190730-18:33:31] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20190730-18:33:31] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20190730-18:33:31] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20190730-18:33:31] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20190730-18:33:31] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20190730-18:33:31] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
[20190730-18:33:32] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=11136 connected to X11rdp_pid=11141 X11rdp_uid=1008 X11rdp_gid=1009 client_ip=10.64.27.2 client_port=45509
[20190730-18:33:32] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20190730-18:33:36] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: connect failed trying again...
[20190730-18:33:36] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20190730-18:33:40] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: connect failed trying again...
[20190730-18:33:40] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20190730-18:33:44] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: connect failed trying again...
[20190730-18:33:44] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20190730-18:33:48] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: connect failed trying again...
[20190730-18:33:48] [ERROR] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: error in trans_connect chan
[20190730-18:33:48] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:52154)
[20190730-18:33:48] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.64.5.120:3389)
[20190730-18:33:48] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20190730-18:33:48] [DEBUG] Closed socket 19 (AF_UNIX)
[20190730-18:33:48] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
```

**xrdp-sesman.log**

```
[20190730-18:32:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 1 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20190730-18:32:31] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sesman with pid 11093
[20190730-18:32:31] [INFO ] listening to port 3350 on 127.0.0.1
[20190730-18:32:46] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 51792
[20190730-18:32:46] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username walker, ip 10.64.27.2:57868 - socket: 12
[20190730-18:32:46] [INFO ] starting Xorg session...
[20190730-18:32:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:5910)
[20190730-18:32:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6010)
[20190730-18:32:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6210)
[20190730-18:32:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20190730-18:32:46] [INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 11099
[20190730-18:32:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20190730-18:32:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20190730-18:32:46] [INFO ] Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log
[20190730-18:32:46] [CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 11100) to exit
[20190730-18:32:46] [CORE ] window manager (pid 11100) did exit, cleaning up session
[20190730-18:32:46] [INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 11099
[20190730-18:32:46] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets:
[20190730-18:32:46] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_socket_10
[20190730-18:32:46] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: failed to delete /tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_socket_10
[20190730-18:32:46] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username walker, display :10.0, session_pid 11099, ip 10.64.27.2:57868 - socket: 12
[20190730-18:33:31] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 52154
[20190730-18:33:31] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username walker, ip 10.64.27.2:45509 - socket: 12
[20190730-18:33:31] [INFO ] starting Xorg session...
[20190730-18:33:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:5910)
[20190730-18:33:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6010)
[20190730-18:33:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6210)
[20190730-18:33:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20190730-18:33:31] [INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 11139
[20190730-18:33:32] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20190730-18:33:32] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20190730-18:33:32] [INFO ] Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log
[20190730-18:33:32] [CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 11140) to exit
[20190730-18:33:32] [CORE ] window manager (pid 11140) did exit, cleaning up session
[20190730-18:33:32] [INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 11139
[20190730-18:33:32] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets:
[20190730-18:33:32] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_socket_10
[20190730-18:33:32] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdpapi_10
[20190730-18:33:32] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: failed to delete /tmp/.xrdp/xrdpapi_10
[20190730-18:33:32] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username walker, display :10.0, session_pid 11139, ip 10.64.27.2:45509 - socket: 12
```

Any advice that can point me towards a solution would be awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change in `xrdp.ini`

```
allow_channels=false
```

Reaction?